# ComboBox list: How can I execute code when a certain item in a combo box is clicked or highlighted?

Tags: combobox, vb6

I'm building a handy application for myself. It's a program that contains links to others programs, so that I can start them from a central place. I already have the design, but I want my application to start a program when an item is clicked in the combo box. For example: Microsoft Office Word is an item in that list, when I click on it, I want it to launch Microsoft Office Word. How can I do that? Arready tried the following:

```
Private Sub programCombo_Click()
  'If programCombo.List(1) = "Word" Then
    'Shell "C:\Program Files\Everything\Everything.exe", vbNormalFocus
  'End If
  Select Case UCase(programCombo.Text)
    Case "Word"
      Shell "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\WINWORD.EXE", vbNormalFocus
    Case "Excel"
      Shell "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\Excel.EXE", vbNormalFocus
  End Select
End Sub
```

But this doesn't do anything. I sort of made it work, but only if I edit the "Text" property of the Combo box. When I change "programCombo.List(1)"to item 2 in the combo box list, it doesn't do anything.

I know I can do all of this with buttons, but if I do that, it will be a big, ugly and clumsy program.

Comment: You will need to respond to an event, such as `Click`.

Comment: You need to add the `if` statements under `programCombo.SelectedIndexChanged`. This is if you make the _DropDownStyle_ as _DropDownList_ and add the values under Items Collection. Else use `programCombo.KeyDown`, check for _Enter_ key as `If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then` and use the `If` statements inside it.

Comment: Will try your solution as well, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You stated in your description what needs to happen - `start a program when an item is clicked` - so the solution is to respond to a `Click` event on the combobox.  The following code is a basic example of what I am talking about.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
   programCombo.AddItem "Word"
   programCombo.AddItem "Excel"
End Sub

Private Sub programCombo_Click()
   Select Case UCase(programCombo.Text)
      Case "WORD"
         Shell "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\WINWORD.EXE", vbNormalFocus
      Case "EXCEL"
         'shell excel
   End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried your code, but still nothing. It gave me an error at first. Telling me that "End select" was missing, so it seems he "runs" the code, but nothing is started.

Comment: Replace my comment `shell the app` with a valid shell command.

Comment: I know. I used: Shell "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\WINWORD.EXE", vbNormalFocus, but still nothing

Comment: Verify your PathName.  On my computer I successfully launched Word with `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\WINWORD.EXE"`.

Comment: I have Office 2016, not 2013, so the pathname is correct. I used a different application, but still the same. When I use a button, it works...

Comment: I updated my code to be more specific to your situation.  Try it again.

Comment: That is exactly the same as my code. I updated my code aswell.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was being a bit dumb. UCase converts it to uppercase, and I used "Word" and not "WORD". Good thing I searched for UCase. Thanks for the suggestions guys.

I'm now gonna crawl up in a corner and cry for being so dumb.